# cart checkout wont work

Tags: cart

I have big problems with my payment methods on my website. When I adda to cart one product and proceed to checkout, on the second step where i need to(as a guest) fill the fields with informations name , adress etc., when I click on the continue button  and magento does some loading but finishes and stays on the page. I cant complete a simple shopping! any ideas? i'm using a downloaded theme, but I dont think tahat is the reason.

Help guys!

Comment: check your error log

Comment: You may not "think" the downloaded theme is the problem, but that doesn't mean it's not. Change your theme back to base/default and try it then to be sure. Aside from that, without some kind of detailed error report, this is an impossible question to answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can Go to /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtm and then add:

```
<fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```

instead:

```
<fieldset>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I've replaced the code and it works like a charm...Thanks!

Comment: are you Welcome